# Can I do a projection query on a property which is a Collection, like java.util.List?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

If so, how?

I set the property as a type :List, which at runtime is just a List I believe anyways.

However, when adding a projection, I get the error that List is not supported

query.addProjection(new PropertyProjection("ListofLongs", List.class);

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type: interface java.util.List
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.RawValue.asType(RawValue.java:58)
```

I've also tried passing in the class of the projection property as null than tried to cast RawValue into a List... no go. (and supported by the stacktrace on the other method due to RawValue.asType triggering the exception)

Is there some sort of undocumented limitation on projection queries against properties which are multivalue/collections?

Comment: List is an interface. Shouldn't you use ArrayList.class instead?

Comment: I believe I've tried this, but I will do so again and report back with my findings.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type: class java.util.ArrayList
 at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:94)
 at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PropertyProjection.<init>(PropertyProjection.java:36)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GAE Datastore definitely supports [projection queries on multi-valued properties](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries#Java_Projections_and_multiple_valued_properties).

But as docs state: you will not get back properties as a whole list, but only the list values that matches your query as separate Entities.

Rationale: projection query is a "fake" query that only uses index and recreates Entities returned from data in index. It never touches the actual Entities (that's the whole point - to be fast). Since every value in multi-valued property (collection, array) creates a separate index entry, the result of projection query is separate (fake) entities.

Comment: I see, so the query would be returning a List<Long>, instead of List<Entity>.getProperty("propertyThatIsArrayList<Long>")? 

Basically the query I was testing this on was meant to grab ALL data stored in the property of type List<Long>. I thought I could speed this up with a projection because I do not need the other properties in the Entity. Is this possible? 

I realized I'm asking the same question sort of but I'm having a hard time comprehending the logic/concept you typed in your Rationale section. Could you exlaborate? Thanks alot!

Comment: If your entity contains a list with three properties, projection query will not return one entity with this list property, but three entities with a single values. Docs clearly explain this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still pretty new to the "NoSQL" fashion of databases. Im not too sure if this would net that big of a performance gain due to the enhanced amount of entities, not to mention the readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the class that the list contains. For example, if you have a list of strings property, you should pass String.class instead of List.class.

Then, as mentioned in a different answer, you will get a separate copy of the entity for each matching value in the list property.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/projectionqueries#Java_Projections_and_multiple_valued_properties

Comment: Please add relevant parts from your link here.